# Angular Universal shows Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-universal

I have installed Angular Universal on my Angular9 application running the following: `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine`
After then, since I have lazy loading routings I have added: `ModuleMapLoaderModule` to `app.server.module.ts`.

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ModuleMapLoaderModule } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
    ModuleMapLoaderModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppServerModule {}
```

After accessing the localhost:4200 URL an error appears on the TERMINAL:
[image]

And this on the browser:

[image]

server.ts file:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app() {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/rapitec/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run() {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

Comment: Show your server.ts file. It's likely you haven't upgraded that file after migrating to angular 9

Comment: Added. Note that I have added NG9 before adding NG Universal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who face the same issue, below is a solution:

`@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader` is no longer required unless you are using the deprecated string based lazy loading, which from the error it doesn’t appear to be the case.

https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1606